# initialize log4j properties in mule 3 dynamically

Tags: log4j, mule

I use mule 3.3.1 CE.

I have log4j_dev.properties for development environment. similarly , I have it for other environments.

I wonder if there is a way to initialize log4j properties based on current environment **via mule**

Please note:

---

Similar to log4j properties , I have environment_*.properties.
I was able to initialize it as follows

1) setting environment variable in server

```
   $ export ENV=dev
```

2) mule-config:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:environment_${ENV}.properties"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mule does not use system properties to resolve placeholders, but JVM arguments.

Please add the following line to your wrapper.conf:

```
wrapper.java.additional.<n>=-DENV=dev
```

and it will do the trick.

Comment: It is error-prone (in my opinion) because 1) the change cannot be validated while the system admin makes it. 2) Updating server configuration file before deployment is not recommended

Comment: You can pass the argument to the mule script by running it using -M-DENV=dev if you prefer